# EntityFramework Update Deletes Record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I'm developing a MVC4 app using .Net4.5, EF5 and MSSQL 2008R2. I'm using Db Context and autogenerated entity classes/models and the Unit of Work pattern.

When I attempt to update a table record through the Edit ActionResult method, the record gets deleted when I data updated was originally null, like adding a middle name for example.

I can follow the object from the ActionResult to the GenericRepository to the UnitOfWork Save() where the db context savechanges() is called. The data is there until then. After that, I'm not sure how to debug it.

So, any help with either debugging or with resolving this would be appreciated. I can successfully create and delete table records. I also tried simply using the db context in the Edit ActionResult with the same delete results. I tested the mapped stored procedure, which updated correctly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(v_Demographics vm)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                unitOfWork.DemographicsRepository.Update(vm);
                unitOfWork.Save();
                //db.Entry(vm).State = EntityState.Modified;
                //db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(vm);
    }


public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
   {
    internal SEntities db = new SEntities();
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(AIPIMSEntities db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.dbSet = db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        db.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}


 public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private AIPIMSEntities db = new AIPIMSEntities();
    private GenericRepository<v_Demographics> demographicsRepository;

    public GenericRepository<v_Demographics> DemographicsRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this.demographicsRepository == null)
            {
                this.demographicsRepository = new GenericRepository<v_Demographics>(db);
            }
            return demographicsRepository;
        }
    }


    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: may help if we could see the Generic Repository code since this is what is doing the update

Comment: Chris, I put an edited version in my original post.  Here's the unedited generic repository.

Comment: Chris, thanks for you help, but I discovered it was a MSSQL view issue.  It's helps to have a weekend off.

Comment: you should add this as your answer and accept to close off the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the delete error was caused by a MSSQL view.  The code here is based upon this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), and works very now.